# loading multiple viewcontrollers in mainviewcontroller

Tags: iphone

Has a mainviewcontroller which as uiimageview and uitoolbar  and when button is pressed on uitoolbar it start loading multiple view controllers one after the other based on nstimer. I want to make this mainviewcontroller as the container for loading multiple view controllers one after the other based on nstimer and uitoolbar always shows below. Don't want to add toolbar as subview in each view controller. how can i do that.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
// Displays UIImageView
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]
                         initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ka1_046.png"]];
myImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubview:myImage]; 
// create the UIToolbar at the bottom of the view controller
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 425, 320, 40)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

//Add Play Button
self.playButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playpauseAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 UIBarButtonItem *play = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.playButton];

-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}else{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
   if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                            target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                             userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }} }


  - (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender{  
     First *first = [[First alloc] init];
     first.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
     CATransition *transitionAnimation = [CATransition animation];   
     [transitionAnimation setDuration:1];
     [transitionAnimation setType:kCATransitionFade];
     [transitionAnimation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
     [self.view.layer addAnimation:transitionAnimation forKey:kCATransitionFade];
     [self.view addSubview:first.view];
     [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
     [first release];   
     self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(Second) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];     
     }
```

In the same way loads other multiple view controllers one after the other based on nstimer. So how can i make this mainviewcontroller as container to load these multiple view controllers one after the other based on nstimer and having uitoolbar below always.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How about presenting your viewControllers with presentmodal then dismiss it that way too. Or rather use navigation controller. So u can manage to switch to views.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay in the main view controller, then by definition you cant push any other view controllers. What you CAN do, is just create all of these other things as UIView's and then add them as subviews to your main VC. It means that all of your code will be in the same .m file, but that shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: It is confusing to add multiplevcs as uiview to the subview of main vc where to handle transition between vcs got to use addtosubview removefromsubview

Comment: im sorry but I dont really understand what you're asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: i added UIView *baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];[self.view addSubview:baseView]; on top of UIImageView and in the displayviewaction if i add [baseView addSubview:first.view];
so that as per playpauseAction it replaces UIImageView with first.view after 11 seconds as subview. It gives message that use of undeclared identifier baseView.